# Problem Updating Initramfs While Setting up Dual Boot Encryption

Tags: dual-boot, encryption

I've been trying to set up encrypted dual boot Windows 10 and Xubuntu 20.04 on my new ASUS ZenBook Flip 14 UX461FN-DH74T using these instructions: https://www.mikekasberg.com/blog/2020/04/08/dual-boot-ubuntu-and-windows-with-encryption.html.

Unfortunately, I got stuck on the last step. While updating initramfs I got the error message:

```
cryptsetup: WARNING: target 'luks-06866a0d-3196-400a-86ce-7fd6eef414d6' not found in /etc/crypttab
```

Rebooting just goes to initramfs shell.

This is the output of sudo blkid /dev/nvme0n1p6:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p6: UUID="06866a0d-3196-400a-86ce-7fd6eef414d6" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="9f5429dc-27e4-4721-8d8b-5b011b70c6c8"
```

And this is what's in /etc/crypttab:

```
# <target name> <source device> <key file> <options>
# options used:
#     luks    - specifies that this is a LUKS encrypted device
#     tries=0 - allows to re-enter password unlimited number of times
#     discard - allows SSD TRIM command, WARNING: potential security risk (more: "man crypttab")
#     loud    - display all warnings
nvme0n1p6_crypt UUID=06866a0d-3196-400a-86ce-7fd6eef414d6 none luks,discard
```

Can anyone give me some suggestions on how to troubleshoot this problem? I'm a beginner so please explicitly spell out any steps to be taken.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: For some reason cryptsetup wanted 'luks-06866a0d-3196-400a-86ce-7fd6eef414d6' in the name field of crypttab instead of 'nvme0n1p6_crypt'.

Comment: Did you simply replace `nvme0n1p6_crypt` with `luks-06866a0d-3196-400a-86ce-7fd6eef414d6` in `/etc/crypttab` and it worked?

Comment: Yes. Although I have done this process a second time not too long after the original post and 'nvme0n1p6_crypt' worked.